# Spring Boot intercept all exception handlers

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying to perform some common logic that applies to all my `@ExceptionHandler`s in code. I know I can write a `HandlerInterceptor` to intercept happy paths. But I would like to hook into the exception handling lifecycle so that I can execute some common logic such as logging, before the error response is rendered.

Is there anyway to do this in Spring Boot / Spring MVC? I would like to avoid having to write a servlet filter for this purpose if possible.

Comment: Are you talking about `UncaughtExceptionHandler`? OR you coudl have a proxy like Spring does to intercept error?

Comment: No, I haven't actually not-handled any exceptions. I just want to do some post-processing for every exception handler that I have. It could involve reporting on the status code, for instance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have a solution. It's about using `HandlerInterceptor.afterCompletion` method. However, there is a line in the [documentation of this method](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html#afterCompletion-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Exception-) that states that:

> Note: Will only be called if this interceptor's preHandle method has successfully completed and returned true!

So the trick is to also implement the `preHandle` and make it return `true`.

Now my interceptor looks like this:

```
@Component
public class MyInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) throws Exception {
        // perform common logic here
    }
}
```

One thing to be aware of though is that if you have a chain of interceptors and an interceptor before this one throws an exception, this interceptor won't get a chance to execute. So if we reorder the interceptor chain so that `MyInterceptor` is right at the top, it will intercept all requests.

Comment: I don't think implementing the preHandle and to make it just return true is needed since it is doing the same thing in HandlerInceptorAdapter class.

Comment: How do we `reorder the interceptor chain so that MyInterceptor is right at the top`?

Answer (score 8):

There is a way with `@RestControllerAdvice` and `@ExceptionHandler`, an example:

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class GlobalControllerExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(value = {DeniedPermissionException.class})
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN)
    public String deniedPermissionException(DeniedPermissionException ex) {
        return "Denied permission";
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(value = {ConstraintViolationException.class})
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public String constraintViolationException(ConstraintViolationException ex) {
        return "Bad request";
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(value = {Exception.class})
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    public String internalServerError(Exception ex) {
         return "Internal error";
    }
}
```

*`DeniedPermissionException` is a custom exception.

Comment: Sorry I don't think I've explained myself clearly. In your example above, how would I intercept each of the exception handlers above to do some common stuff? One crude way would be to put that common logic in a private method and call that method 3 times. But I am looking for an interceptor style solution.

Comment: @adarshr Depending on your needs, if you want to have a filter for all types of errors, you just have to have the internalServerError method, if you want to distinguish in several types of errors but maintain a common behavior, I can think of two options, either create a private method and invoke it directly or use AOP. But the second option seems to me to be introducing overengineering

Comment: I think I have found the solution :-) Sorry, I should've RTFM'ed first.

Comment: Does this controller intercepts all exceptions raised in a spring boot context? what if spring boot uses other protocols to communicate with other systems (other than REST)? Is there a more generic annotation similar to `@RestControllerAdvice`? Thank you

Comment: This only handles exceptions thrown by controllers, not all exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a Spring Boot concern. This is really a Spring MVC concern. One good approach is to implement the `HandlerExceptionResolver` or extend from something like `ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver`. The implementation needs to be given a higher precedence than the default exception resolvers (which all run with the lowest precedence). And if you want to retain the existing behavior of the default resolvers but only trap the exception for something cross-cutting like logging or tracking, then just return null for the `ModelAndView` and Spring will ensure other default resolvers are invoked as before.