# Testcases for RestController by disabling Interceptor with MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, interceptor, spring-restcontroller, mockmvc

Hi I am trying to write testcases for RestEnd Points.
I have RestController, Interceptors, ControllerAdvice classes.

I want to write negative testcases that throws exception where i can check status that is mapped in ControllerAdvice

But here the interceptors are getting called and I am not able to test other negative status coded mapped in controller advice.

Can you please help me how can I disable interceptor for testcases.

Below is code snippet:

```
    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;
    @Before
    public void setup() {
................
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
    }

  @Test
  public void verifyTest() throws Exception {
    Mockito.when(service.getAccount(any(String.class), any(String.class))).thenThrow(new UserDefinedException("test failure"));

    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post(SOFTWARE_ENDPOINT).content(REQUEST_BODY)
      .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
      .andExpect(status().isUnprocessableEntity());
  }
```

Here interceptor is invoked as part of testcases. It should not go through interceptor.
How can i disable interceptor for rest end points.

Comment: can you post some more information, which interceptor is being invoked, stack trace/exceptions if you are getting? Does the interceptor override `preHandle` and `afterCompletion` methods?

Comment: Yes interceptor override prehandle methods

Comment: It would be helpful if you could share the interceptor code which is being executed. Also, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48786793/2326172) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48785878/spring-boot-intercept-all-exception-handlers) might be helpful in understanding why it might be going to interceptors.

Comment: @ Component
public class TestInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
 @ Autowired
 private HManager mn;

 @ Autowired
 private AConfig app;

 @Override
 public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
   throws Exception {

  String id= request.getHeader("acctid");
  if (hm.isEnabled("hh", id)) {
   return true;
  } else {
   throw RestExceptionHandler.generateException("eeror code",
     "Currently service unavailable, please check with the administrator");
  }
 }


}

Comment: The above is the sample code snippet.